# How do I change CSS priority on magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, css

The button on this page along with other objects are not receiving its module parameters, instead they are receiving from (index):275 which I was not able to discover where it comes from. How do I track back this to remove them? or change the order?

Thank you!
[image: magento inspect page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to track where this CSS is coming from through the Inspector. If it says index (275 being the line the code is at) it means it’s either inline CSS or that a specific CSS file is called via a xml layout file for this particular page. Use the inspector to check where this CSS is coming from and check if this page has a particular xml file associated to it. If it’s a CMS page or a block, check in the back-end if there is anything specified in the design tab. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Jake, but not yet :) ... when I trace it, it only shows the link checkout/onepage/cadastro which does not seems to help in any way since it is the page in question. In addition it is not only this button, but several objects from this checkout module. It was working, It stopped after I update the module and the template. So they both could be the problem.

Comment: How do you trace it? Did you check in the source tab of the inspector? Have you checked if the module is calling a specific CSS file that's overriding your own CSS? Either through an xml file or in the back-end? When you say it’s no longer working, are you talking about the module?

Comment: Hi Jake, thank you! :) I managed to find looking for btn-success in all files of the module. At the end I found out that it was calling at app/design/frontend/fortis/default/template/MOIP/onestepcheckout/page/1column.phtml. See below...
            .btn-success {
                background: <?php echo $botao_cor_success ?>;
                border-color: transparent;
I did not even look further, just erase all style entrances on this file and all get back to work. :)

Comment: Glad you could find it and get back to work, if my answer helped you make sure to mark it as accepted